# JS: ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0, Nativescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript, nativescript

I have the issue with Json.parse.

I used this only in a model like between:

```
export class EventsGps {
    eventsgps_id: string;
    latitude: String;
    longitude: string;
    gps_serial: string;  
    event_data: EventData;
    ev_data: any;

    constructor(obj: any) {
        this.ev_data = JSON.parse(obj.event_data);
        this.event_data = this.ev_data;
        this.eventsgps_id = obj.eventsgps_id;
        this.latitude = obj.latitude;
        this.longitude = obj.longitude;
        this.gps_serial = obj.gps_serial;
    }
}
```

In html I can't show data because show this error, this error only for those data

```
            this.eventsgps_id = obj.eventsgps_id;
            this.latitude = obj.latitude;
            this.longitude = obj.longitude;
            this.gps_serial = obj.gps_serial;
```

event_data looks good.

Can you ask me any idea, how to solution this?

When I remove JSON.parse all looks good, only event_data doesn't show because from ws event data arrive like this:

```
JS:   "event_data": "{\"alarmtype\":\"call\",\"datetime_hb\":\"2018-03-29 12:24:32\",\"hb_serial\":\"aaaa\"}",
```

Thank you

UPDATE:

I write this service code to get all data:

```
  public getgps(): Observable<EventsGps[]> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('x-access-token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
    return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.getsgps), {
      headers: headers
    })
      .pipe(map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();
        if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
        } else {
          return res.StatusDescription.map(gps1 => {
           console.log('getgps')
          console.log(gps1)
            return new EventsGps(gps1);
          });
        }
      }))
  }
```

Result:

```
: {
JS:   "eventsgps_id": "1",
JS:   "latitude": 50.2029,
JS:   "longitude": 20.3939,
JS:   "gps_serial": "testgps",
JS: }
```

I write this service code to get all data events

```
 public getallevents(): Observable<EventsGps[]> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('x-access-token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
    return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.getallevents), {
      headers: headers
    })
      .pipe(map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();
        if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
        } else {
          return res.StatusDescription.map(gps => {
           console.log(gps)
            return new EventsGps(gps);
          });
        }
      }))
  }
```

Results:

```
JS: gps events
JS: {
JS:   "id": "1",
JS:   "alarmtype_id": 2,
JS:   "alarmnumber": 5,
JS:   "device_serial": "testgps",
JS:   "acted": 1,
JS:   "user_acted": "31000000000000000000000000000000",
JS:   "dtm_acted": "2018-06-26 03:06:49",
JS:   "event_data": "{\"alarmtype\":\"call\",\"datetime_hb\":\"2018-03-29 12:24:32\",\"hb_serial\":\"aaaa\"}",
JS: }
```

### Obj

```
constructor(obj: any) {
    console.log('obj')
    console.log(obj)
     ....
        }
```

Result:

```
JS: obj
    JS: {
    JS:   "id": "1",
    JS:   "alarmtype_id": 2,
    JS:   "alarmnumber": 5,
    JS:   "device_serial": "testgps",
    JS:   "acted": 1,
    JS:   "user_acted": "31000000000000000000000000000000",
    JS:   "dtm_acted": "2018-06-26 03:06:49",
    JS:   "event_data": "{\"alarmtype\":\"call\",\"datetime_hb\":\"2018-03-29 12:24:32\",\"hb_serial\":\"aaaa\"}",
    JS: }
JS: obj
   : {
    JS:   "eventsgps_id": "1",
    JS:   "latitude": 50.2029,
    JS:   "longitude": 20.3939,
    JS:   "gps_serial": "testgps",
    JS: }
```

console.log(this.event_data)
[image]

Comment: if you `console.log(obj.event_data)`, do you get `{\"alarmtype\":\"call\",\"datetime_hb\":...`?

Comment: Yes, but when I used `JSON.parse(obj.event_data);` I get correct format data

Comment: Then it sounds like the parse function is failing if it logs properly

Answer (score 1):

Your `obj.event_data` is `undefined` at the time you try to parse it.

This will parse without any issue:

```js
JSON.parse("{\"alarmtype\":\"call\",\"datetime_hb\":\"2018-03-29 12:24:32\",\"hb_serial\":\"aaaa\"}");
```

While this will result in the `Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0` error:

```js
JSON.parse(undefined);
```

---

**Update**

After looking at your updated question, your first example (`gps1`) indeed has an undefined `event_data` property.

```js
const gps1 = {
  "eventsgps_id": "1",
  "latitude": 50.2029,
  "longitude": 20.3939,
  "gps_serial": "testgps",
}

JSON.parse(gps1.event_data); // Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

Comment: you are saying to write like this: `this.ev_data = JSON.parse(undefined); this.event_data = this.ev_data;`

Comment: No, I am absolutely not saying that. I'm saying that you're trying to parse an `undefined` value instead of a JSON string. As to why that value is `undefined`, I can't speculate because I don't have the context.

Comment: He's saying that maybe your data is undefined. So you should check if it is undefined before parsing it.

Comment: All data I get correct not undefined. :( Because I can show in html those event_data.

Comment: If you're convinced that all your data is correct, add a data object to your question so that we can try for ourselves to reproduce the issue. At this point, all we have is your guarantee that your data is correct, while I can pretty much guarantee that it is not. So provide the data, and we'll see.

Comment: And your first example (`gps1`) has no `event_data` property, hence it is `undefined`, as I said.

Comment: Please look again my post. Look that my event_data show correct

Comment: Only one of the two objects you're using has the `event_data` property set.

Comment: In this code that I post, only event data works, other object show error. I can't understand, because when I tried in web app this works very good. In mobile I don't understand why?! Where is undefined, I can't understand and I can't show :(

Comment: There's only so many different ways that I can explain this: you're trying to parse an `event_data` property of an object that does not have an `event_data` property.

Comment: I found error, thanx. I write `this.event_data= obj.event_data && JSON.parse(obj.event_data);`